# Is there any way to uniquely identify a user in a firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Currently, We are integrating firebase crashlytics. I have set user identifer using "Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier("xxxx")" and also, see the user id in the crash report. Is there any way, to filter out a particular user crash report/ events?.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#set-user-ids):

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId("12345");
```